# How to get PFFile from disk?

Tags: ios, caching, parse-platform, pffile

I want to get a PFFile from disk.  I learned here that Parse caches all PFFiles as they are downloaded.  I am wondering now how to retrieve that cache.  What is the correct path.  The path I use is suggested [here](https://parse.com/questions/how-to-access-the-local-path-to-a-cached-pffile)

`NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Caches/Parse/PFFileCache/%@", pffile.name];`

```
NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
```

data is always nil.

Am I using the correct path? `/Caches/Parse/PFFileCache/`

Comment: Why not just save the file data in a location of your choice for the files you need?

Comment: Because the PFFile does not contain the data.  I still have to request the data in the file saved in the parse servers.  I'm not a fan of how they did it.

Comment: try finding out the path they are saving their cache to after saving a file and reproduce that path.

Comment: Any update here? Did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description of the problem you should use a slightly different process. Use the `PFFile` interface initially, but then store the `url`s from the files for the case where you need to access the file data later. In this way you have a direct link to the file data and can use a normal connection or session to download.

If you don't actually need the `PFFile` for anything about the download then using the REST interface may be more suitable for you.

Another alternative is to make the same request which originally returned the file information to you, but instructing the API to use cached information only. This is done by setting `cachePolicy` to `CACHE_ONLY` on your `PFQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this in Swift for some time, and found this thread which aided in the answer here:

```
let fileURL: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + ("/Caches/Parse/PFFileCache/\(checkedRemoteAsset.name)")
```

Thanks to you KKendall!